# Odds Dice Rolls

Tags: probability

Guys so I have a question.

Let's say I'd like to calculate the odds of rolling either $10+$ (10 or more), $5+$  (5 or more) or $15+$ and an exact $1$ on a icosahedron dice.

Here's what I did:

For $10+$, the odds of not rolling is $\frac{9}{20} = 0.45$. For $5+$, $\frac{5}{90} = 0.20$. For $15+$, $\frac{14}{20} = 0.70$.

So the odds for $10+$, $5+$ and $15+$ are, respectively, $0.55$, $0.80$ and $0.30$. Odds for rolling exactly $1$ is $\frac{1}{20} = 0.05$.

The probability of all this events ($10+$ **or** $5+$ **or** $15+$ **and** $1$) would be what?

Comment: How many times do you roll? (You can't get 15+ and 1 simultaneously on the same roll, of course!)

Comment: Note that any roll of 10+ is also a roll of 5+. Any 15+ is also a 5+, including the case where the 15+ is somehow combined with a 1 (on a second roll?). In what way is this question different from just asking for the odds of rolling 5+ in one or more of the various ways you can roll 5+?

Answer (score 1):

If I can understand this question, you are asking for the probability you do all of the following possibilities($1, 5+, 10+, 15+$) consecutively.

If you are looking for the exact sequence: $10+, 5+, 15+, 1+$, the probability is just $.55*.8*.3*.05$.

If you are looking for a sequence just containing those for numbers, just do $4!$(number of possible orderings)$*.55*.8*.3*.05$.

Comment: What I'd like is: $10+$ then $5+$ then $15$ then $1+$, one of the following.

Comment: @user618548 That's an even worse description than your original version of the question. The phrase "one of the following" is supposed to come _before_ whatever the "following" things are--otherwise they aren't "following" at all! And if you meant to refer to "10+ then 5+ then 15 then 1+", that's just one thing; where are the other things you want "one of"?